# single_user not found?

Tags: python, add-on

I am creating an add-on that inserts a cloth modifier shape key (every frame) using the API.

It works like it should, but
However, I am getting a frame by frame warning of an error in the CUI.

What could be the cause of this?

```
    obj = context.scene.theChosenObject

        for i in range(appendFrame_start, appendFrame_end + 1):

            # multiply interval
            x = i * keyFrame_interval
            if x > appendFrame_end: break

            bpy.context.scene.frame_set(x)

            print("aaaaa")
            bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply_as_shapekey(keep_modifier=True, modifier=cloth_modifier_name)
            print("bbbbb")

            obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks[cloth_modifier_name].name = shapeKeys_baseName + "(" + str(x) + ")"

            if x-(2*keyFrame_interval) >= appendFrame_start:
                # append before defoem keys
                obj.data.shape_keys.key_blocks[shapeKeys_baseName+"("+str(x)+")"].value = 0.0
```

omitted

erro message:

```
RNA_boolean_get: OBJECT_OT_modifier_apply_as_shapekey.single_user not found.
RNA_boolean_get: OBJECT_OT_modifier_apply_as_shapekey.merge_customdata not found.
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, I wouldn't worry about it if it works as expected. The console output is meant for advanced users. So unless you have an error displayed in the interface or something doesn't work you can safely dismiss it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I was worried about it, so I appreciate your help.